# What does it mean "standard of English" in the following conext?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean a "**standard of English**" in the following context?

I have to fill in a document and I really don't understand what "standard of English" means. Does it mean to a certification like IELTS, TOEFL or it's about the BrE, AmE, CaE etc.?

This is what the document says:

> The language of instruction in our university is / is not English. If
>   English is not the principal language  of instruction, **please state
>   the standard of English**_________________________.

Comment: Is there a period? I can't really tell what it means.

Comment: Yes, there is a full stop in the end of the line.

Comment: I suspect the intended *meaning* is actually *Please specify the **status** of English* (given it's not the *primary* language of instruction, is English even relevant or useful at all at this university?). But it's inherently vague / imprecise, and that would probably still be the case if we had the *entire* context (the whole document).

Comment: The entire context is an official document about going for one month to an English speaker university as a guest student. They ask in this document  (only in the phrase that I showed) about the home university language.

Comment: In that case I think it's just a stupid question (by the "English speaker university", not you). What they really care about is really nothing to do with whether or not English is the "language of instruction" at your *current* university - they just want to know how good *your* English is. But listing off any formal "certification" you might have isn't necessarily a good guide as to whether you'd be able to keep up with lectures delivered in what would be (to you) a foreign language anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about technicalities of English language certifications, rather than about learning the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I read "standard" as "level of competence". If you have a formal qualification in English, that could be the answer, but it could be something vaguer such as "reading knowledge but limited conversation". I think.

Comment: Basically, I agree but the layout of the question is confusing.